# IOS Contact images Not showing in my tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am getting contact images from `AddressBook` from this code

```
NSData  *imgData = CFBridgingRelease(ABPersonCopyImageData(ref));
       imgdata = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

        NSLog(@"image data is=%@",imgdata);

       // [iamgeArray addObject:imgdata];
        NSLog(@"image array=%@",iamgeArray);
```

and I save these images in `imageArray` but they are not showing in `mytableview` image my cell code is

`[ cell.imgcintact setImage:[iamgeArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]];`

Array returns `"image":1234554`

How can I show this image in my `tableviewcell` also I am using `sectiontableview`

Comment: Add please return of NSLog(@"image data is=%@",imgdata);

Comment: Once you populate the array are you calling `[self.myTableView reloadData]`?

Comment: Did you make sure `imgcintact` was added as a subview of your UITableViewCell?

Comment: Is `ref` an  `ABRecordRef`? It may be more beneficial to show the context in which your example is used.

Comment: yes it is ABRecordRef and array have images i print it on concole please tell me how i show these images in uitableview section